# FaceBook Graph as3 air application problems

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook, graph, air

I have 2 problems to solve ...

I can't set a picture as a user-created page wallpaper and i also cant "like" this same page using a Facebook Desktop Graph API request.

Somebody can give me some insight into how to use the Facebook Graph API for AS3 to change the wallpaper on a user created page and also set the "like" status for that page of a user? Is this even possible?

Cheers

Comment: I modified your wording slightly user727782 to clarify your question. If I've made an error at all please advise or edit your question further. I did this in an attempt to spare you downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question isn't clear, are you trying to set a background image in your iframe, or set the Page's profile picture?

The second part isn't possible, there's no Facebook API which allows a Page to be liked

Comment: Hey Igy thanks for help ! I'm trying post a photo in a page profile like a feed .... i was trying feed/photos but that was not working fine ..